# Conditional statement based on user's input

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, user-input, addition

I'm trying to answer a question based on a dictionary of active and terminated employees:
Part A - Create a dictionary of active employees (with hourly pay) and a list of terminated employees

Part B - Collect the user's input of what they would like to do (show the list, add an employee, remove an employee)

Part C - Create a conditional statement that does the following based on the user's input:

Show: Prints the dictionary
Add: Asks for employee and hourly rate and adds that key/value pair to the employee dictionary
Remove: Removes the employee from the active dictionary and adds that employee as the first element in the terminated list

I'm pretty sure I've got part A and B, but I'm struggling with part C because I can't get the first if statement to work and I'm not sure how to add the employee, rate and value pair to the dictionary.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
active = {
    'Josh Allen': '$1,000/hr',
    'Lamar Jackson': '$2,000/hr',
    'Russel Wilson': '$5,000/hr',
    'Patrick Mahomes': '$4,000/hr'
}


print(active)

terminated = ['Tom Brady', 'Phillip Rivers', 'Drew Lock', 'Sam Darnold']
print(terminated)

active.update({'Drew Brees': '$3,000/hr'})
print(active)

terminated.remove('Tom Brady')
print(terminated)

if user types 'Show':
  print(active)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if user types 'Show':
```

You have the right idea, you just need to get the user's input. I will point you towards [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_user_input.asp) resource for getting user's input and see if you can then figure it from there.